# How to exit a command run on a for loop in linux bash

Tags: linux, bash, for-loop, break

I am running the fol loop on the few hosts from `/tmp/hosts` file and then simply running a command `storagegrid-status` and the doing `grep` as follows.

```
for i in $(cat /tmp/host); do
    echo $i
    ssh  $i "storagegrid-status" | grep -i Release
done
```

When I'm running above command i see its kind of getting hang on the loop on the command, however it takes max 5 sec to complete this action. Now i want to know how to exit from the command and release the loop so it can go on the next iteration in the loop.

any help will be much appreciated.

### EDIT:

While using "-m1" with grep..

```
# storagegrid-status | grep -m1  "StorageGRID Release"
StorageGRID Release            11.4.0.2             Verified
Traceback (most recent call last):
        5: from /usr/local/servermanager/reader.rb:90:in `<main>'
        4: from /usr/local/servermanager/reader.rb:90:in `loop'
        3: from /usr/local/servermanager/reader.rb:91:in `block in <main>'
        2: from /usr/local/servermanager/reader.rb:23:in `current_status'
        1: from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/bycast/servermanager/StandardInfo.rb:11:in `standard_info'
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/bycast/servermanager/StandardInfo.rb:11:in ``': Broken pipe (Errno::EPIPE)
```

Comment: Once grep is done the loop will continue with the next host. What do you mean *i want to know how to exit from the command and release the loop*?

Comment: Hi, ssh is not 'lighting fast' and your command may be slow. Check it like this `time storagegrid-status`.

Comment: @Ivan, thank you so much , indeed that's  the case `storagegrid-status`  gives the grep output but then hangs there for a long time , its max takes 5 sec to result the output but then doesn't comes out for a minute or so hence i want this commad to be exited after 5-6 sec so it may to to next hosts.

Comment: @oguzismail, thanks for the input, you ae right indeed thats how it should work but in my case it does the `grep` thing and returns the output but doesn't come out of the command and that's where it doesn't go to next host ...

Comment: You may be looking for `grep -i -m1 Release`, it'll exit after the first match.

Comment: @oguzismail, this partially works, i am adding this on the post .

Comment: @kulfi then try to use `timeout` like this `timeout 0.1 storagegrid-status | grep ...`

Comment: @Ivan This works  just fine, however i find out the reason as its a ruby script which user is using and the ruby script been kept under bash script with "--watch" , so i asked the just use the command and for loop start working as expected after removing "--watch" command.